# How can I append number of available records to dropdownlist options?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I hope the title of my thread makes sense.

We are building a car dealership web app that allows potential car buyers to determine what type of car fits their budgets and needs.

As a result, we have dropdownlist of car make, car model, car condition, milage, price range, among others.

The code below shows a dropdownlist of make of car.

When a user selects his/her preferred make of car, the models associated with that make are automatically loaded into the second dropdownlist.

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <span style ="font-family:Arial">Select Make : </span> 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMake" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMake_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text = "------" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br /><br />
        <span style ="font-family:Arial">Select Model : </span> 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlModel" runat="server" Enabled = "false" AutoPostBack = "true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlModel_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Text = "------" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Submit New Request"></asp:button><br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblResults" runat="server" Text="" Font-Names = "Arial"></asp:Label>        
    </div>
    </form>



     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            If Not IsPostBack Then
                ddlMake.AppendDataBoundItems = True
                Dim strConnString As [String] = ConfigurationManager _
                 .ConnectionStrings("amsconstr").ConnectionString
                Dim strQuery As [String] = "select vehicleId, Make from MakeModel"
                Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandText = strQuery
                cmd.Connection = con
                Try
                    con.Open()
                    ddlMake.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    ddlMake.DataTextField = "Make"
                    ddlMake.DataValueField = "vehicleId"
                    ddlMake.DataBind()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw ex
                Finally
                    con.Close()
                    con.Dispose()
                End Try
            End If
        End Sub
   Protected Sub ddlMake_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            ddlModel.Items.Clear()
            ddlModel.Items.Add(New ListItem("--Select Model--", ""))

            ddlModel.AppendDataBoundItems = True
            Dim strConnString As [String] = ConfigurationManager _
                       .ConnectionStrings("amsconstr").ConnectionString
            Dim strQuery As [String] = "select vehicleId Employee from MakeModel " _
                                        & "where vehicleId=@vehicleId"
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehicleId", _
                                 ddlMake.SelectedItem.Value)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery
            cmd.Connection = con
            Try
                con.Open()
                ddlModel.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                ddlModel.DataTextField = "Model"
                ddlModel.DataValueField = "VehicleId"
                ddlModel.DataBind()
                If ddlModel.Items.Count > 1 Then
                    ddlModel.Enabled = True
                Else
                    ddlModel.Enabled = False
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            Finally
                con.Close()
                con.Dispose()
            End Try
        End Sub
  Protected Sub ddlModel_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

            Dim strConnString As [String] = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conString").ConnectionString
            Dim strQuery As [String] = "select VehicleId, Model from MakeModel where VehicleId=@vehicleId"
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnString)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehicleId", ddlModel.SelectedItem.Value)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery
            cmd.Connection = con
            Try
                con.Open()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            Finally

                con.Close()
                con.Dispose()
            End Try
    End Sub
```

This works fine.

We would like to append the number of available records for each make of a car.

For instance, on the Make of a car dropdownlist, we have something like:

Mazda
Mercedez Benz
Toyota,
etc

We would the user to know how of particular make is available like:

```
Mazda (10)
Mercedez Benz (2)
Toyota (7)
```

How do I add available number of cars for a particular make of that car?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your SQL statement so it returns all you need. Instead of just:

```
select VehicleId, Model from MakeModel.....
```

use something like:

```
select VehicleId, (Model + '(' + (select count(*) from MakeModel B where a.ID=b.ID) + ')') as Make from MakeModel A...
```

..which is not nice but would work. Play with SQL Server CTE to make the code nicer. Or even better put the final code to stored procedure and call this procedure instead.

Also one note - try to reduce repetitive code. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ivansivak, thanks but i am getting this error:

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ')' to data type int.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the CONVERT() function.

```
select VehicleId, (Model + '(' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, (select count(*) from MakeModel B where a.ID=b.ID)) + ')') as Make from MakeModel A
```